Incremental Variance Estimations on SPX
I am developing a program aimed at estimating the daily implied volatility of SPX using an incremental variance approach. My current methodology involves employing a root-finding algorithm coupled with interpolation techniques to identify the strike price for each expiry that corresponds to a 0.159 delta (1 standard deviation). This synthetic strike price is then used to estimate the percentage OTM as an indicator of the expected movement for the SPX, effectively representing a one-standard deviation movement.
While this method yields results, it is somewhat cumbersome, and I am seeking a more streamlined approach. I am aware that using ATM-implied volatility is not ideal due to the vol curve, which results in an overestimation compared to actual market. I also know model-free implied volatility is a possibility; however, as shown in the equation below, it relies on averages, and I'm fairly certain this would introduce inaccuracies into my framework, especially when I move away from SPX and use it on more illiquid assets.
$$\text{VIX}^2 = \frac{2}{T} \sum \frac{\Delta K}{K^2} e^{RT} Q(K) - \frac{1}{T} \left( \frac{F}{K_0} - 1 \right)^2$$
For further clarification, the point of this model is to essentially inform traders what movements are being priced at around major events, such as CPI releases, giving some insight into what the market thinks is going to be important.

While your current methodology using a root-finding algorithm and interpolation to identify the strike price corresponding to a 0.159 delta is a valid approach, it can be enhanced for a more streamlined and accurate estimation of SPX's daily implied volatility.
Instead of relying solely on the 15.9 delta strike, leverage the model-free implied volatility (MFIV) as a robust foundation. MFIV effectively summarizes information from both the Black-Scholes implied volatility and past realized volatility, making it a powerful predictor for liquid assets like the SPX. Calculate MFIV using current market prices of SPX options across various strikes and maturities.
To further refine your model and account for market skews, particularly around major events like CPI releases, incorporate asymmetric implied volatility functions (e.g., SABR, Vanna Volga). These functions can better capture the nuances in market expectations compared to symmetric functions. Fit these asymmetric functions to observed option prices to model the volatility smile or skew, enabling a more accurate estimation of implied volatility, especially at the tails of the distribution where extreme movements are more likely.
To ensure smooth and arbitrage-free interpolation of the volatility surface, apply the stochastic collocation technique. This method eliminates inconsistencies in the data, resulting in more reliable estimations across different strikes and maturities.
For a deeper understanding of potential market movements, consider simulating arbitrage-free implied volatility surfaces. While computationally intensive, this approach offers a comprehensive view of potential outcomes, valuable for stress testing and understanding your model's behavior under different market conditions.
Additionally, weighting implied volatilities based on open interest or trading volume can give more emphasis to the more liquid options, which are generally more representative of market sentiment.
